# Code produces wrong result with ForAll, why?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am trying to use `ForAll` quantifier on `b`, so formula `a * b == b` with every `b` would give me `a == 1` as result. I implemented this in the code below (Z3 python):

```
from z3 import *

a, b, a1 = BitVecs('a b a1', 32)

f = True
f = And(f, a1 == a * b)
f = And(f, a1 == b)

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(b, f))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

I expected Z3 gives me `a = 1` at the output, but I got `Unsat` instead. Any idea on where the problem is?

(I suspect that I dont use ForAll properly, but not sure how to fix it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this:

```
a, b, a1 = BitVecs('a b a1', 32)

f = True
f = And(f, a1 == a * b)
g= True
g = And(f, a1 == b)

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(b, ForAll(a1,f == g)))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat
```

output:

```
a = 1
```

Other form:

```
a, b, a1 = BitVecs('a b a1', 32)

f = True
f = And(f, a1 == a * b)
g= True
g = And(g, a1 == b)

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(b, ForAll(a1,f == g)))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

output:

```
a = 1
```

Comment: Juan, this works, thanks! However, I would change the ForAll into `ForAll([b, a1],f == g)`. Again, thanks!

Comment: Btw, do you have any suggestion for the original code? Your code introduces a new formula `g`, while the original code only has 1 formula `f`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking Z3 (among other things) to find a single *a1* that is equal to *b* for all values of *b*. This is not possible. Your problem is not with Z3 but with basic logic.

Comment: Vladimir, do you have any suggestion on how to fix the original code? Juan gave me some hints but that is still not on the original code (in the original question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this:

```
a, b = BitVecs('a b', 32)

a1 = a*b
a2 = b


s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(b, a1 == a2))

if s.check() == sat:
     print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
     print 'Unsat'
```

the output:

```
a = 1
```

Other way:

```
a, b = BitVecs('a b', 32)
a1 = a*b
a2 = b
f = True
f = And(f, a1 == a2)


s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(b, f))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

the output:

```
a = 1
```

Comment: The second solution is really interesting. I never think it is possible to just use a1 and a2 like that, without declaring `a1 = BitVec(32)`. But it seems to work, as proved by your code. Any explanation to this????

Comment: Btw, I am still wondering why my original code returns 'Unsat'. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to verify the formula `a * b == b` for all possible `b`. You can use the following code.

```
from z3 import *

a, b = BitVecs('a b', 32)
s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(b, a * b == b))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

This code runs in a blink of the eye, but your code overloads the solver and takes relatively a long time to complete.